# python sort dictionary of lists based on single list

Tags: python, pandas, list, dictionary, nested

I have imported a csv file and stored its data into a dictionary with pandas as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(inputfile)
mydict = df.to_dict(orient='list')
```

Now, I would like to use one list to

1. set new keys
2. sort other lists

I have achieved something similar by doing so:

```
gb = df.groupby('time')
ts = dict(list(gb))
```

The "problem" is that I have a dictionray of dataframes instead of a dictionray of lists.

**BASIC EXAMPLE**

csv file:

```
var1 var2 var3 time var4
1    0    1.1  0    34
2    0    2.1  1    150
3    0    6    2    16
1    0    1.1  0    34
2    0    2.1  1    150
3    0    6    2    16
1    0    1.1  0    34
2    0    2.1  1    150
3    0    6    2    16
```

dictionary imported with pandas

```
mydict = 
{'var1': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 
'var2': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
'var3': [1.1, 2.1, 6.0, 1.1, 2.1, 6.0, 1.1, 2.1, 6.0], 
'time': [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2], 
'var4': [34, 150, 16, 34, 150, 16, 34, 150, 16]}
```

what I would like to achieve is

```
mydict2 = 
{0: {'var1':[1,1,1], 'var2':[0,0,0], 'var3':[1.1,1.1,1.1], 'var4':[34,34,34]},
 1: {'var1':[2,2,2], 'var2':[0,0,0], 'var3':[2.1,2.1,2.1], 'var4':[150,150,150]},
 2: {'var1':[3,3,3], 'var2':[0,0,0], 'var3':[6,6,6], 'var4':[16,16,16]}}
```

So far what I have obtained is similar, but for each `time` I get a dataframe:

```
ts = {0:    var1  var2  var3  time  var4
0     1     0   1.1     0    34
3     1     0   1.1     0    34
6     1     0   1.1     0    34, 
1:    var1  var2  var3  time  var4
1     2     0   2.1     1   150
4     2     0   2.1     1   150
7     2     0   2.1     1   150, 
2:    var1  var2  var3  time  var4
2     3     0   6.0     2    16
5     3     0   6.0     2    16
8     3     0   6.0     2    16}
```

where, if I type `type(ts[0])` I get `<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>` which is ok (I can get the job done), but what if I wanted a dictionart of lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```py
x = df.groupby("time").agg(list).to_dict("index")
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
{0: {'var1': [1, 1, 1], 'var2': [0, 0, 0], 'var3': [1.1, 1.1, 1.1], 'var4': [34, 34, 34]}, 
 1: {'var1': [2, 2, 2], 'var2': [0, 0, 0], 'var3': [2.1, 2.1, 2.1], 'var4': [150, 150, 150]}, 
 2: {'var1': [3, 3, 3], 'var2': [0, 0, 0], 'var3': [6.0, 6.0, 6.0], 'var4': [16, 16, 16]}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use dict comprehension with `orient='list'` in [`DataFrame.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html):

```
d = {k: v.to_dict(orient='list') for k, v in df.set_index('time').groupby('time')}
print (d)
{0: {'var1': [1, 1, 1], 'var2': [0, 0, 0], 'var3': [1.1, 1.1, 1.1], 'var4': [34, 34, 34]}, 
 1: {'var1': [2, 2, 2], 'var2': [0, 0, 0], 'var3': [2.1, 2.1, 2.1], 'var4': [150, 150, 150]}, 
 2: {'var1': [3, 3, 3], 'var2': [0, 0, 0], 'var3': [6.0, 6.0, 6.0], 'var4': [16, 16, 16]}}
```